# $f : \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times_n$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Is there any function $f : \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^\times_n$ that is invertible?

By invertible, I mean it given $y \in \mathbb{Z}^\times_n$, it should be easy to find $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Of course there are. A trivial example is the identity function except $f(0) = 1$.

Comment: @HenrickHellström, but not every element of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ (if the latter is meant to be the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$). The former has order $n$ while the latter has order $\varphi(n)$.

Comment: Henricks proposal works for $n$ being prime but not in the general case.

Comment: I think this depends on the definition of $\mathbb Z_n^\times$. If we exclude not only 0 but also all divisors of 0, and $n$ is composite, then there are more bad points, yes. In such case a trivial example is the identity function except $f(x) = 1$ if $x|0$.

Comment: @sadnoe : You also need to give us an idea of what you mean by "invertible". 'How' invertible does it need to be? Also, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+{%28n+-+\phi%28n%29%29+%2F+n}+for+n%3D0+to+2^50) graph might help: you're going to have trouble making an invertible function with such a difference

Comment: @HenrickHellström: Such a definition might well invalidate the 'invertible' term in the required definition. Hopefully sadnoe will clarify what is envisaged

Comment: If it does invalidate the 'invertible' term, then, by the pigeon hole principle, there are *no* functions that satisfy the criterion in the question.

Comment: Indeed, but there might be "less-bad" constructions such as
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x+1) & x|0
\\x & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
Depending on just what the use case is

Comment: Sounds like we have an answer for both possible definitions of "invertible". 1) yes - with 2 examples; 2) no - by the pigeon hole principle.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  As it stands, your parenthesis does not correspond to any notion of inversion that I am familiar with.  Also please define your notation, e.g., the $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ notation.  And why is this a cryptography question?  Please add some context or motivation, and tell us what you've tried to do on your understand to figure out the answer for yourself.  Have you reviewed standard material on modular arithmetic?

Comment: Not convinced I could tag this well, because given the map doesn't have to preserve any form of structure its hard to argue this is anything to do with group theory / modular arithmetic

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, $|\mathbb Z_n|=n$, whereas $|\mathbb Z_n^*|=\varphi(n)<n$. So, by the [pigeon-hole principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) there cannot be a mathematically invertible function
$f:\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_n^*$.

So, lets relax our idea of what 'invertible' means a bit. How about ensuring every element of $\mathbb Z_n^*$ has a preimage? Yep, we can do that. To use a couple of examples from my and  Henrick's [comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14671/f-mathbbz-n-rightarrow-mathbbz-times-n#comment29804_14671):
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  1 & x|0
\\x &\text{else}
\end{cases}
  \qquad\text{or}\qquad
g(x)=\begin{cases}
g(x+1) & x|0
\\x & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$
The first is much easier to study. With the exception of $1$, each preimage is unique, which is nice. However, $1$ may have an incredibly large number of preimages (roughly $n-\varphi(n)$). By contrast, the second scheme should mitigate this difficult behaviour at zero, but you pay for it by sacrificing the uniqueness of other preimages.

Just what sort of scheme you require (and if such a scheme exists) really does depend on your specific use case.

One possible use might be that you have to invert the function $f$, and you have a second function that will confirm if you have the 'correct' preimage. In this case, an intuitive inverter would be return $x$ if $x\neq1$, or if $x=1$ sequentially test all possible preimages.

How bad would the 'brute force' section of these algorithms be? Well,$n+1-\phi(n)$ (ie the number of preimages of zero) is maximal when $\phi(n)$ is minimal and is always less than $n$. However, for certain 'bad' choices of $n$ (values who's prime factors occur with small exponents) this value may (compared to $n$) be very small indeed.

Comment: The value of $n - \varphi(n)$ is highest for $n$ that consist of a product of the smallest primes, each with exponent $1$. For $n = 2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13\times17\times19\times23$ it is approximately $5/6$.

Comment: Also, testing if $x|0$ is just a matter of testing if $GCD(x,n) = 0$.

Comment: Re 1: for 2^n it's half. Re #2: I don't see your point? Certainly they are Quick to calculate, but inverting is harder

Comment: If $GCD(x-1,n) \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}(x) = x$. Otherwise, if $GCD(x-2,n) \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}(x) = \{x-1,x\}$ etc. I think this recursion has an estimate worst case running time of $ln(n)$.

Comment: $n$ that is a product of the smallest primes is a 'worse' case than powers of $2$.

Comment: I thought so, but wasn't at my computer at the time - in which case I misunderstood what your 5/6 was referring to (I think I was expecting you to write $1/6$ for what you meant and this threw me). But yes (and the proof of this is obvious from writing $\phi(n)=\prod_{p|n} p^{n_p-1}(p-1)$)